# Use Sounds in java

Tags: java

Hi…I searched the site and found another code that works correctly.

Now I have another problem:

When I create object from blow class and send the address of audio to its constructor, I have to send the complete address like:

“C:\Documents and Settings\TheHero\My Documents\NetBeansProjects\project1\src\project1\s1.wav”

But I want to use this code just with name of sound like : “s1.wav”.

I copied the sound into the src folder and then use  “s1.wav” and the result was 
”java.io.FileNotFoundException”.

If I use complete address of sound, when I run the program on another computer it does not work. I’m right?

//********************************

public class MusicPlayer {

```
private String filename;

public MusicPlayer(String filename) {
    this.filename = filename;
}
public void play() {
    try {
            InputStream in = new FileInputStream(filename);
            AudioStream as = new AudioStream(in);
            AudioPlayer.player.start(as); 

    } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
    }          
}
```

//****************************

I have the same problem with images. When I use these codes, I must use complete address of image

```
     File input = new File(imageName);
     image = ImageIO.read(input);
```

Please Someone help me!I really need these!
Thank you all guys….

Answer (score 6):

You could use URLs in order to retrieving image and sound files.  For example:

```
new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/com/foo/myimage.png")));
```

... will retrieve the image file from package com.foo assuming it is on your classpath somewhere (e.g. bundled in a jar file).

**EDIT**

For sound clips you take a similar approach; e.g. something like:

```
URL url = getClass().getResource("/com/foo/sound.wav");
AudioStream as = new AudioStream(url.openStream());
```

Comment: Could u please explain more? What u've written is for images, what about sounds?
Can I put sound in resource folder?

Comment: @Hamed - I've expanded my answer.  Hope that helps.

Comment: HAHAHA!!! I made it, it workes now!
just send the relative address to constructor!

Answer (score 1):

FileInputStream(filename) is the key.

The filename can be absolute or relative. You seem to have two problems.

1). relative paths, **s1.wav** will be relative to the working directory of the running application, that's almost certainly not your src directory.

2). absolute paths on a different machine does

```
C:\Documents and Settings\TheHero\My Documents\NetBeansProjects\  etc.
```

actually exist on the remote machine?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of copying the file into the **src**, copy it into the **bin** folder.  This is where execution happens.

If that doesnt work, you can call:

```
Properties sysProps = System.getProperties();
```

Then iterate through the Properties and look for one that's your current working directory.  That's where you put your wav file.